# Minimum Texture Size limit in CUDA

Tags: cuda, textures

Is there any minimum size limit for 2D CUDA Textures?

I know there are maximum limits on Fermi (65535 x 65535) and G80 (65535 x 32768).
But are there any minimum limits?

Comment: From a performance point of view, going thru the PCI-express bus (much slower than memory bus today) for a "tiny" operation on a "small" amount of data is certainly not worth the effort.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch

i'm doing following:
1. Read an image to device.
2. Resize it
3. Bind the resized image to texture.


resizing is done on the device.

if the width of resized image reaches 80, texture binding fails.

Comment: Can you post some code?  AFAIK, there should not be a minimum other than perhaps 1x1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum texture size is 1 texel: so 1 in each dimension of the texture.  [1] for 1D, [1x1] for 2D, [1x1x1] for 3D.